# Laravel append data count to database object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello i have this function

```
public function readData(){
$TableB1 = \DB::table('users')
->join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
->join('meetings', 'users.id', '=', 'meetings.owned_by_id')
->select(
   'users.name as name',
   'group_user.user_id as id',
   'groups.name as groupname',
    )
->get();
foreach ($TableB1 as &$data){
    $meetings = \DB::table('meetings')
                ->where('company_id', 1)->where('owned_by_id', $data->id)
                ->where(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->month);
    echo $meetings->count();
}

return $TableB1;

}
```

i retrieve some data from database and return them and use AJAX Call to use them later

The problem is i have a table called users and table called meetings

i want to know how many meetings every user done everyday

so to do this i made a for each to take the `user_id` and use it to get the count
 of meetings done by each user

for example in meetings table i have a `owned_by_id` field which have the `user_id`

so what the code does if it found for example if `owned_by_id(6)` repeated in

meetings table 4 times it will return 4

but this is what i get in the browser

instead what i want to get is something like this

im using Laravel 5.7 and sorry i know my question is unclear this is the 1st time i have ever asked question on stackoverflow
[Image](https://ibb.co/k69730n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a new column in the `select()` using the [`COUNT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) SQL statement:

```php
->select(
    'users.name as name',
    'group_user.user_id as id',
    'groups.name as groupname',
    \DB::raw('(
        SELECT COUNT(meetings.id) FROM meetings GROUP BY meetings.owned_by_id
    ) as meetings')
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but i tried it and i get this error
Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select `users`.`name` as `name`, `group_user`.`user_id`

Comment: hello your query do exactly what i want phpmyadmin SQL
but in laravel it gives me this error
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'meetings' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.`name` as `name`, `group_user`.`user_id` as `id`, `groups`.`name` as `groupname`, meetings = ( SELECT COUNT(meetings.id) FROM meetings GROUP BY meetings.owned_by_id ) from `users` inner join `group_user` on `users`.`id` = `group_user`.`user_id` inner join `groups` on `groups`.`id` = `group_user`.`group_id` inner join `meetings` on `users`.`id` = `meetings`.`owned_by_id`)

Comment: Thank you very much im very sorry but i now i get Empty [] in the browser

Answer (score 1):

If you want count of meetings then you may use laravel eloquent method with is: withCount();

Like this:

```
$users = User::with('meetings')->withCount('meetings')->get();
```

If you will do this then you will get meetings_count with your user object.

And if you have still any doubt you may refer following link:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Thnak you!